# How to read the class of a Scala object extending Any but not AnyRef?

Tags: scala, reflection

I have an heterogeneous List like the following one:

```
val l = List(1, "One", true)
```

and I need to filter its objects by extracting only the ones belonging to a given Class. For this purpose I wrote a very simple method like this:

```
def filterByClass[A](l: List[_], c: Class[A]) =
  l filter (_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass() == c)
```

Note that I am obliged to add the explicit conversion to AnyRef in order to avoid this compilation problem:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : _$1 where type _$1
required: ?{val getClass(): ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
both method any2stringadd in object Predef of type (x: Any)scala.runtime.StringAdd
and method any2ArrowAssoc in object Predef of type [A](x: A)ArrowAssoc[A]
are possible conversion functions from _$1 to ?{val getClass(): ?}
l filter (_.getClass() == c)
```

However in this way the invocation of:

```
filterByClass(l, classOf[String])
```

returns as expected:

```
List(One)
```

but of course the same doesn't work, for example, with Int since they extends Any but not AnyRef, so by invoking:

```
filterByClass(l, classOf[Int])
```

the result is just the empty List.

Is there a way to make my filterByClass method working even with Int, Boolean and all the other classes extending Any?

Comment: Would `filterByClass(l, classOf[java.lang.Integer])` be acceptable?

Comment: What an awful data structure to have to work with! How did you end up with such a thing?

Comment: I am quite surprised as well. Must have been a very annoying bug! Nevertheless, having a default match block to handle java primitives could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite my solution could be less elegant than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611666/how-to-read-the-class-of-a-scala-object-extending-any-but-not-anyref/5611828#5611828) I find mine quicker and easier. I just defined a method like this:

```
private def normalizeClass(c: Class[_]): Class[_] =
  if (classOf[AnyRef].isAssignableFrom((c))) c
  else if (c == classOf[Int]) classOf[java.lang.Integer]
  // Add all other primitive types
  else classOf[java.lang.Boolean]
```

So by using it in my former filterByClass method as it follows:

```
def filterByClass[A](l: List[_], c: Class[A]) =
  l filter (normalizeClass(c).isInstance(_))
```

the invocation of:

```
filterByClass(List(1, "One", false), classOf[Int])
```

just returns

```
List(1)
```

as expected.

Answer (score 13):

The `collect` method already does what you want. For example to collect all `Int`s in a collection you could write

```
xs collect { case x: Int => x }
```

This of course only works when you hardcode the type but as primitives are handled differently from reference types it is actually better to do so. You can make your life easier with some type classes:

```
case class Collect[A](collect: PartialFunction[Any,A])

object Collect {

  implicit val collectInt: Collect[Int] = Collect[Int]({case x: Int => x})

  // repeat for other primitives

  // for types that extend AnyRef
  implicit def collectAnyRef[A <: AnyRef](implicit mf: ClassManifest[A]) =
    Collect[A]({ case x if mf.erasure.isInstance(x) => x.asInstanceOf[A] })
}

def collectInstance[A : Collect](xs: List[_ >: A]) =
  xs.collect(implicitly[Collect[A]].collect)
```

Then you can use it without even passing a `Class[A]` instance:

```
scala> collectInstance[Int](l)
res5: List[Int] = List(1)

scala> collectInstance[String](l)
res6: List[String] = List(One)
```

Comment: That's a good solution. Thanks. I must say I am a bit surprised you need something so verbose to accomplish an apparently trivial task, and a bit disappointed by the fact that Scala, despite its claims, treats, at least in this case, primitive types in a way even less uniform and trasparent than Java.

Answer (score 3):

Using isInstanceOf:

```
scala> val l = List(1, "One", 2)
l: List[Any] = List(1, One, 2)

scala> l . filter(_.isInstanceOf[String])
res1: List[Any] = List(One)

scala> l . filter(_.isInstanceOf[Int])
res2: List[Any] = List(1, 2)
```

---

edit:
As the OP requested, here's another version that moves the check in a method. I Couldn't find a way to use isInstanceOf and so I changed the implementation to use a ClassManifest:

```
def filterByClass[A](l: List[_])(implicit mf: ClassManifest[A]) =
  l.filter(mf.erasure.isInstance(_))
```

Some usage scenarios:

```
scala> filterByClass[String](l)
res5: List[Any] = List(One)

scala> filterByClass[java.lang.Integer](l)
res6: List[Any] = List(1, 2)

scala> filterByClass[Int](l)
res7: List[Any] = List()
```

As can be seen above, this solution doesn't work with Scala's Int type.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question: how could I write the filterByClass method? I need some generic that works with any class.

Answer (score 1):

The class of an element in a List[Any] is never classOf[Int], so this is behaving as expected.  Your assumptions apparently leave this unexpected, but it's hard to give you a better way because the right way is "don't do that."

What do you think can be said about the classes of the members of a heterogenous list? Maybe this is illustrative.  I'm curious how you think java does it better.

```
scala> def f[T: Manifest](xs: List[T]) = println(manifest[T] + ", " + manifest[T].erasure)
f: [T](xs: List[T])(implicit evidence$1: Manifest[T])Unit

scala> f(List(1))
Int, int

scala> f(List(1, true))
AnyVal, class java.lang.Object

scala> f(List(1, "One", true))
Any, class java.lang.Object
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Is this what you want?

```
scala> val l = List(1, "One", true)
l: List[Any] = List(1, One, true)

scala> l filter { case x: String => true; case _ => false }
res0: List[Any] = List(One)

scala> l filter { case x: Int => true; case _ => false }
res1: List[Any] = List(1)

scala> l filter { case x: Boolean => true; case _ => false }
res2: List[Any] = List(true)
```

Comment: That doesn't answer my question: how could I write the filterByClass method? I need some generic that works with any class.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, this problem reduces to find a map between a primitive and the corresponding boxed type.
Maybe a help can arrive from `scala.reflect.Invocation` (not included in the final version of 2.8.0), the `getAnyValClass` function in particular (here slightly edited)

```
def getAnyValClass(x: Any): java.lang.Class[_] = x match {
  case _: Byte    => classOf[Byte]
  case _: Short   => classOf[Short]
  case _: Int     => classOf[Int]
  case _: Long    => classOf[Long]
  case _: Float   => classOf[Float]
  case _: Double  => classOf[Double]
  case _: Char    => classOf[Char]
  case _: Boolean => classOf[Boolean]
  case _: Unit    => classOf[Unit]
  case x@_        => x.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass
}
```

With this function the filter is as easy as

```
def filterByClass[T: Manifest](l:List[Any]) = {
  l filter (getAnyValClass(_) == manifest[T].erasure)
}
```

and the invocation is:

```
filterByClass[Int](List(1,"one",true))
```